# P8Z77V built in ethernet fails with Code 10

Tags: hardware-failure, gigabit-ethernet

I have an Asus [P8Z77-V](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8Z77V/) motherboard with a built in intel 82579V adaptor.  For some odd reason its being detected as 82579LM. I'm running windows 8, and the system worked properly before. Its a [known issue](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/115062/) with the board but the utility meant to fix it either crashes or tells me there's nothing to do. I've also tried the dos version of the utility off a windows 98 liveusb, but it just sits there. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, for some reason cold booting the system worked for me, I unplugged the mains connection to the system, let it sit overnight and it both detects the correct adaptor type and functions perfectly.