# PC no longer finds network adapter

Tags: windows-7, networking, ethernet, desktop-computer

Yesterday I came to find my computer no longer connected to the internet. It is hard wired directly to the router with an ethernet cable. When I started to investigate  the problem, I found out that it was registering the fact that the ethernet cable was plugged in. I unplugged the cable from both the router and pc. This did nothing. I then restarted my pc. Now when I trouble shoot network problems, the message I receive is "Windows could not find a driver for your network adapter." I don't not have a delicate network card, I just plugged the cable into the motherboard.

There was a big thunderstorm yesterday, could that have fried the network card on the motherboard and not hurt anything else? All other functionality of the pc is fine. The pc is running windows 7.

Comment: Might sound a bit unusual, but could you try leaving the PC unplugged overnight? [I've had wierd issues with NICs fixed doing that](http://superuser.com/questions/734083/p8z77v-built-in-ethernet-fails-with-code-10) before.

Comment: @Journeyman Geek I second that. Only one time so far I certifiably lost on-board function (graphics) during a thunderstorm, but nothing else was noticeably affected by it. I installed a replacement video card and  the system functioned just as before for years. A storm do not have to ‘fry’ anything, only to build up some 10 Volts of static electricity, store it in dust-bunnies inside the case, and back-feed an unprotected lead to a 5-Volts MOSFET if and when that lead happens to sink charge - that is, powered up and active.

Comment: If the storm has damaged your ethernet port it will also have fried the router ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Not necessarily, the storm could have turned any number of BJT’s, for example, into diodes, resistors and not shorts. All of which still conduct, but detrimental to two-way signal paths.

Comment: I'll leave it unplugged overnight and while I'm at work tomorrow to see what that does.

Answer (score 0):

The odds are that the thunderstorm wouldn't have damaged your ethernet adapter but not anything else, especially because its not a dedicated ethernet card. What is the motherboard that you have, and have you tried reinstalling any of the drivers for your specific motherboard?

Comment: Have you tried another device (perhaps borrowed) plugged into the Ethernet? That would determine if it is a PC issue or router issue. And yes, it is *possible* for lightning, or an inductive surge from it, to damage a single chip -- especially the Ethernet chip, which is exposed to voltage surges carried by the cable.

Comment: He stated that the Ethernet card he has is not a separate chip but rather is attached to the motherboard itself, which is why I find it rather unlikely that just the Ethernet functionality of the motherboard would be destroyed.

Comment: If there was only a common voltage over the Ethernet cable, then you're possibly correct -- but it's *also* possible there was a *differential* voltage across the conductors, which could destroy the interface chip, despite ESD protection.