# Intel 82579V LAN driver dropping out

Tags: windows-7, networking, drivers, lan

My PC has an Intel 82579V Gigabit Network Connection and the on-board LAN adapter has started misbehaving over the last few days. When I boot up, the PC has no LAN connection. The entry in device manager shows an error (yellow triangle).

If I uninstall the driver and restart (warm boot), it works properly until I close down, but next time I boot up, the problem occurs again. I've gone round this cycle over several days and it's consistent.  The network never drops once operating correctly, and since I had this problem, has never worked after a cold boot.

When this first happened, it was using a 2012 driver, so I downloaded the latest driver from Intel's site - it's recent, the package is dated July 12 2015 - and installed that. It made no difference. The driver extracted automatically from the package is dated May 2 2014.

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate, 64-bit, fully up to date. The machine is a couple of years old and has performed well up to now.

Any suggestions about what might cause powering down to make the LAN adapter lose its grip on the driver like this?

Thanks.

**Update: Aug 3, 2015** - I found that I don't have to uninstall the driver.  Just doing a warm boot after a cold one gets the LAN connection working properly.

**Conclusion: Jan 6, 2016** - A satisfactory conclusion for me, but an unsatisfying end to this question because I can't give an answer that has any useful information: This problem went away after several months of it happening after every cold boot. I had given up trying to change boot settings and did nothing I'm aware of to fix the problem.

Comment: Heya. You might want to post that as an answer. Seems pretty similar to an issue I had ebfore http://superuser.com/questions/734083/p8z77v-built-in-ethernet-fails-with-code-10

Comment: It's not an answer, it just notes that deleting the driver was an unnecessary step and therefore not relevant. The problem remains that after a cold boot, I have no LAN connection.