# Network adapter can't see Ethernet cable after black out (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, ethernet, network-adapter

There was a black out (power failure) in my home. 
After that, I got some problems with my desktop Windows 10 PC.

1. BIOS boot options were reset to defaults (solved).
2. System time was reset (solved).
3. Network adapter can't see plugged Ethernet cable.

I've solved 1 and 2.

**But my network adapter still tells me that there is no any plugged Ethernet cable.**

I have tested it with 3 different Ethernet cables and nothing changed. All of these cables provide my laptop with Internet correctly. So cables are not damaged.

**I already had tried to**

- Reboot PC multiple times.
- Go to Control Panel and turn ON/OFF network adapter.
- I tried to run `netsh winsock reset` from Administrator mode.
- I tried to update network adapter's driver. Windows said that its OK.

What else could I check or try to do with it?

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem.  Have you tried a different network cable?  Do any other devices connect over the LAN (in other words not connected to the wireless access point) work?  You might have to replace the network adapter.  The fact your system had other problems points to a hardware issue caused by the blackout.  This is unlikely to be a driver problem, so reinstalling drivers, or Windows itself WILL NOT solve your problem.  Any additional information should be added to the question instead of a comment.

Comment: Try running from USB flash drive, rather than HDD (e.g. live Linux). If the network adapter does not work that way, it's almost certainly fried. An Ethernet-USB adapter is about US$15 or less.

Comment: this may seem an odd idea but - try leaving your computer unplugged overnight and try in the morning. I had a few other [quirks](https://superuser.com/questions/734083/p8z77v-built-in-ethernet-fails-with-code-10) but its worth a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definitely sounds like a hardware failure with your network card.
When you get a black out, there is sometimes a spike in the power immediately before the power goes out, or when the power comes back on. It isn't usually much but it can take a toll on your hardware.

My suggestion would be to get a pci network card for your system if you have any spare slots on your motherboard. Also, to stop this kind of thing happening again, I would recommend you get a decent surge protector for your PC. Or if you can, run it through a UPS which will help with 'smoothing' the power from the mains by removing some of the spikes.

Comment: I fixed it with a new Network Card.